# Nullable type in x:TypeArguments

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it possible to pass nullable type to XAML generic type arguments(x:TypeArguments) ?

I have:

```
 <base:ControlBase
  x:TypeArguments="sys:Int32"
  ...
```

I need Int32 to be nullable.. something like

```
<base:ControlBase
  x:TypeArguments="sys:Nullable<sys:Int32>"
 ...
```

Which seems to be invalid XML/XAML.

I tried to declare it as `sys:Nullabe&lt;sys:Int32&gt;` too and the error is:

> 'sys.Nullable' is not a valid type name reference for the generic argument

Comment: From the [docs for `x:TypeArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750476%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *If the generic constraints themselves use generic types, the nested constraint type arguments can be contained by parentheses ().*  If that's right you should be able to do `x:TypeArguments="sys:Nullable(x:Int32)"`.  See also [XAML: Using Generic Types in XAML 2009](http://web.archive.org/web/20120118193925/http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx).

Comment: Tried that one too, doesn't work either...

Comment: @PatrickHofman - interesting, thanks.  It seems it should from the docs.

Comment: Yes, strange. Someone else did another suggestion, but that doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible unfortunately. You need to create an intermediate class to overcome this problem (I have tried all possible ways, it just doesn't work).

```
<base:NullableInt32ControlBase ... >
```

Where `NullableControlBase` is the intermediate class:

```
public class NullableInt32ControlBase : ControlBase<int?>
{ }
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried custom XAML Markup extension to take over the typename parsing i.e. `x:TypeArguments="{MyParse sys:Nullable<sys:Int32>}"` or even `x:TypeArguments="{MyParser int?}"`? I think that it just must work properly, but if you tried that and failed again, I'd be very interested in hearing why/what happened?

Comment: No, I didn't try that, just the regular markup. Also the suggestion of dbc under the question doesn't help. I would be interested to see if it is possible to do it the way to describe.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I tried your suggestion. It gives "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  '{local' is an undeclared namespace." on `x:TypeArguments="{local:NullableMarkupExtension sys:Int32}"`. It seems the evaluation of namespaces doesn't quite work since the class does exist.

Comment: I got the same results. I have also tried putting the extension in the default namespace (see [here, option 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and)). The extension itself works fine in all other places, but in `x:TypeArguments` it does not. Seems **directives** simply does not accept markup extensions, my fail here. I'd be very suprised for example if i.e. `x:Name` accepted a markup extension. Somehow, I haven't though about it when considering TypeArguments. For now, I don't see any further options. Btw I tried on Xaml 2006 not 2009.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks for trying. It seems an hiatus in the current implementation. So the intermediate class seems to be the only solution now.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
sys:Nullable`1[System.Int32]
```

> Intellisende and Resharper gives you an error on this, but it should work.