# Two way bindable entry that supports basic types and nullable types

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve perfect MVVM in Xamarin.Forms with Entry.

My model contains properties whose type includes string, int?, decimal?, bool?, etc,. Whenever I bind to a string type, the two way binding works because the text property has a string type (they match). But once you try to bind back to the model and the property is an int or int?, it doesn't update the model's property's value.

During my research and with help from Xamarin support, this was a very helpful thread on how to handle nullable types:

[Nullable type in x:TypeArguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431590/nullable-type-in-xtypearguments)

XAML code:

```html
<controls:NullableIntEntry Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="14" NumericText="{Binding BusinessOwnership, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="lblBusinessOwnership"></controls:NullableIntEntry>
```

BindableEntry (Entry extension) code:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CreditBuilderApp.Controls
{
    public class BindableEntry<T> : Entry
    {
        static bool firstLoad;

        public static readonly BindableProperty NumericTextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("NumericText", typeof(T), typeof(BindableEntry<T>),
                null, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnNumericTextChanged);

        static void OnNumericTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var boundEntry = (BindableEntry<T>)bindable;
            if (firstLoad && newValue != null)
            {
                firstLoad = false;
                boundEntry.Text = newValue.ToString();
            }
        }

        public T NumericText
        {
            get { return (T)GetValue(NumericTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumericTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public BindableEntry()
        {
            firstLoad = true;
            this.TextChanged += BindableEntry_TextChanged;
        }

        private void BindableEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                this.NumericText = (T)Convert.ChangeType(e.NewTextValue, typeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                this.NumericText = default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NullableIntEntry and NullableDecimalEntry (Bindable Entry extension specifying the type):

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreditBuilderApp.Controls
{
    public class NullableIntEntry : BindableEntry<Int32?>
    {

    }

    public class NullableDecimalEntry : BindableEntry<Decimal?>
    {

    }
}
```

Model:

```html
      private int? _businessOwnership { get; set; }
        public int? BusinessOwnership
        {
            get { return _businessOwnership; }
            set
            {
                if (_businessOwnership != value)
                {
                    _businessOwnership = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am actually able to bind to integer, decimal, floats, basically any type that isn't a string, which is a step in the right direction. BUT, to accomplish this, I have to create the BindableEntry above and specify which type it is. (Replace T with int?, T with decimal?, etc,. ALONG with specifying how the e.NewTextValue is casted.

PROBLEM: the below type change conversion is breaking the two way binding.

```html
this.NumericText = (T)Convert.ChangeType(e.NewTextValue, typeof(T));
```

But, that gives me an error (obviously) since this.NumericText is of type T before run time.

So, if I wanted the entry to work for nullable integers, I would need to replace all type T's with int? AS WELL AS change the above code to:

```html
Convert.ToInt32(e.NewTextValue)
```

When I step through the code, whenever I reach the Convert.ChangeType to T line, it exits the frame. There is no error and the page is displayed, but every control after that particular bindable entry, does not have values.

[After stepping through the ConvertType function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTpLt.png)

Let me know if I missed any information. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using value converter, it's lot easier than creating custom controls and confirms to the MVVM pattern.

You can find the code snippet here - https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/60076/#Comment_60076

Comment: Value converters work, but not for nullable types. So, if I am converting between int?(Nullable<int>) and string, I can't return a null. What makes it work is if I return default(int), which is 0.

Comment: @TonyMykhaylovsky, I'm not sure what you mean when you say value converters don't work with nullable types. Of course they do, the return type and the `value` parameter are of type `object`. If you pass in a value type, like `int`, it will get boxed to an `object` reducing the need to manually convert from int? and non-nullable types.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over a year old but found a solution to this question that may help others. If you make the following change to the original code presented it works:

BindableEntry (Entry extension) code:

Change BindableEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) to

```
    private void BindableEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
        {
            var t = typeof(T);
            t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal?))
            {
                var results = decimal.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out var tmpValue) ?
                    tmpValue : (decimal?) null;

                if (results != null)
                    NumericText = (T)Convert.ChangeType(results, t);
                else
                    NumericText = default(T);
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(double?))
            {
                var results = double.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out var tmpValue) ?
                    tmpValue : (double?)null;

                if (results != null)
                    NumericText = (T)Convert.ChangeType(results, t);
                else
                    NumericText = default(T);
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(int?))
            {
                var results = int.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out var tmpValue) ?
                    tmpValue : (int?)null;

                if (results != null)
                    NumericText = (T)Convert.ChangeType(results, t);
                else
                    NumericText = default(T);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NumericText = default(T);
        }
    }
```

I found the missing piece to get this working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015425/invalid-cast-from-system-int32-to-system-nullable1system-int32-mscorlib).
Hope this helps...